# How can I get p5 (processing in Python) to display in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, processing, p5py

There is a [new p5 library in pyPI](https://pypi.org/project/p5/) that can be installed in Google Colaboratory:

```py
!pip install -U p5
import p5
```

However, I have had problems getting the chart to show. It seems to be a problem with glfw - getting it to send the graphics to the right display. I am using this on Win10. *Readthedocs* with installation instructions for p5 is [here](https://p5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

The following example is taken from the p5 repository - https://github.com/p5py/p5

```py
def setup():
    p5.size(640, 360)
    p5.no_stroke()
    p5.background(204)

def draw():
    if p5.mouse_is_pressed:
        p5.fill(p5.random_uniform(255), p5.random_uniform(127), p5.random_uniform(51), 127)
    else:
        p5.fill(255, 15)

    circle_size = p5.random_uniform(low=10, high=80)

    p5.circle((p5.mouse_x, p5.mouse_y), circle_size)

def key_pressed(event):
    p5.background(204)

p5.run()
```

The error messages are:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2146d31dac46> in <module>()
     20     p5.background(204)
     21 
---> 22 p5.run()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/vispy/app/backends/_glfw.py in _vispy_get_native_app(self)
    213             try:
    214                 if not glfw.glfwInit():  # only ever call once
--> 215                     raise OSError('Could not init glfw:\n%r' % _glfw_errors)
    216             finally:
    217                 os.chdir(cwd)

OSError: Could not init glfw:
["Error 65544: b'X11: The DISPLAY environment variable is missing'"]
```